# Getting Number Format Exception while accessing the value from Jsp

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets

code for servlet

```
    String id=request.getParameter("id");
     UserProfileDAO dao = new UserProfileDAO();
     List<UserProfilePojo> list = dao.UserProfile(id);
     request.setAttribute("Profile", list);
     RequestDispatcher view= request.getRequestDispatcher("Profile.jsp");
     view.forward(request, response);
```

Code written in Data Access Object Class

```
public List<UserProfilePojo>UserProfile(String id)
{
    String query ="select fname from registration where Id="+id;
    List<UserProfilePojo> list = new ArrayList<UserProfilePojo>();
    UserProfilePojo User = null;
    try {   
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
                User = new UserProfilePojo();
                User.setFname(rs.getString("fname"));
                list.add(Profile);
        }                                                                                 }
```

Code written in the Pojo Class

```
public class UserProfilePojo
{
 private String fname;
 public String getFname();
        {
            return fname;
        }

        public void setFname(String fname) 
        {
            this.fname = fname;

        }
 }
```

Access through Jsp

```
       <td>${Profile.fname}</td>
```

Exception stack trace

```
    message java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fname"    

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented     

    it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:     

    For input string: "fname"


  root cause

  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fname"
  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

The problem is when the setter method is called from the jsp by using ${Profile.fname} it displays the Number format exception. After researching on this particular exception i got to know that this occurs only when one data type is tried to convert to another data type. I am unable to understand where it is happening in this particular scenario.

Please help me in solving the problem.
thanks
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're trying to access an element in a list without referencing what index it's at.

```
request.setAttribute("Profile", list); //Profile is a List object
```

Use this instead:

```
<td>${Profile[0].fname}</td>
```